# Typeorm eager loading not working on one to one relationship

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node-mysql, node.js-typeorm

Can we eagerly load a one-to-one related entity in typeORM?
I am using TypeOrm in nestjs.
The two One-to_One related entities are driver and job:

in Driver Entity:

```
  @OneToOne(() => JobEntity, job => job.current_driver)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'current_job_id', referencedColumnName: 'job_id' })
  current_job: JobEntity
```

in Job Entity:

```
  @ApiProperty({ type: Number, example: 29 })
  @OneToOne(() => DriverEntity, driver => driver.current_job, { nullable: true, cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'current_driver_id', referencedColumnName: 'driver_id' })
  current_driver: DriverEntity;
```

I have tried to access the eagerly loaded entity on both sides, it's not working on either side.

Comment: Hey, did you tried to set `eager: true`? Also, accordingly to typeorm docs, Eager relations only work when you use find* methods. If you use QueryBuilder eager relations are disabled and have to use leftJoinAndSelect to load the relation. Eager relations can only be used on one side of the relationship, using eager: true on both sides of relationship is disallowed. [docs reference](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations)

Comment: Yeah I have tried that

Comment: I did some tests with a code of mine and everything worked correctly. 
One point: `@JoinColumn` is required and must be set only on one side of the relation (the owner side of the relationship) [link reference](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/one-to-one-relations)

Comment: Also would be good if you add more info about your code to someone can help you. Like the relationship tables, what table has the FK and the complete class of your entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
  @OneToOne(() => JobEntity, job => job.current_driver)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'current_job_id', referencedColumnName: 'job_id' , eager: true})
  current_job: JobEntity
```

true your eager

Answer (score 2):

I was adding @JoinColumn on both sides. It is required only on one side.